# Variable Not Being Set When sh Script is Called With PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php, sh, shell-exec

I currently have a sh script:

```
    location=$1
    imageNumber=$2
    keyword=$3
    page=$4
    imagesInPage=$5
    imagesToGet=$6
    imageUrls=`curl -s "http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[MYAPIKEY]&text=$keyword&per_page=$imagesInPage&media=photos&license=1,2,4,5,7&page=$page" | sed '1,3d' | sed 'N;$!P;$!D;$d' | ./xml_to_urls 2> /dev/nul`

    currentImage=0

    for url in $imageUrls
    do
            if [ $currentImage -ne $imagesToGet ]
            then
                    curl -s "$url" > "$location/$imageNumber.jpg"
            else
                    break
            fi
            currentImage=`expr $currentImage + 1`
            imageNumber=`expr $imageNumber + 1`
    done
```

... which basically requests the Flickr API for a list of images corresponding to the arguments. Then, I loop through the image URLs, saving each one in a specified directory.

The PHP script that calls this is quite long, but here's the line that calls it:

```
shell_exec("./get_images \"" . $dir . "\" " . $currentImageNumber . " \"" . $keyword . "\" " . $page . " 500 500");
```

When I run the command (ex: ./get_images "temp/0.75456300 1297381201" 0 "moose" 1 500 500) on the command line, no problems occur. However, when run by the PHP script, the variable $imageUrls is never set. I can echo out the command I am setting imageUrls to, and that displays the URLs on the page PHP creates, but as far as I can tell, the variable its self is blank.

Any help I could get on this would be great! Please tell me if I should add anything else or if my question is misleading, this is my first post :D! Thanks!

Comment: any reason the whole thing is not one php script?

Comment: Yea, to be practical, I guess that would be the best option, but I just took a class on Unix/C/CGI and I thought I would practice some of the stuff I just learned. I already had the basic format in PHP, so I just made all the other parts in sh/c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding dbl-quotes around the output of your variable assignment for imageList

```
imageUrls="`curl -s "http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/....."
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer